# Updating Ngrx store from material combo-box and then binding to the returned ngrx store data

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx-store

I am just starting to get to grips with Ngrx. I have wired up various controls to update and then return data from my store. Text boxes and check boxes work as expected, however combo boxes are a different storey. I can't get the binding right.

Here are the issues  I face:

1) When I update the value in the combo box my setCurrentBadge function is fired twice

2) The value I have selected from the list in the combo-box called 
`<mat-select class="badge-codes-combobox">` is not visible.

3) The getCurrentBadge function fires, even though this is located in the ngInit life-cycle hook and the page has not reloaded.

4) When I reload the page the getCurrentBadge function fires but the combo-box does not display the returned value.

As far as the code goes I need the badgeCodeSelected($event) to fire just once when the value of the combo box changes. I need the [value]="selectedBadge" to display the selected value and when the page is reloaded I need the combo-box to display the value returned from the store)

Here's my code.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <app-declaration-type
    [errorMessage] = "errorMessage$ | async"
    [displayTypes] = "displayTypes$ | async"
    [declarationTypes] = "declarationTypes$ | async"
    [badges] = "badges$ | async"
    [traderReference]= "traderReference$ | async"
    [selectedBadge] = "selectedBadge$ | async"
    (badgeSelected) = "badgeCodeSelected($event)" 
    (checked) = "checkChanged($event)"
    (traderReferenceSet) = "onBlurTraderReferenceChange($event)"
    >
    </app-declaration-type>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-declaration',
  templateUrl: './declaration-shell.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DeclarationShellComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage$: Observable<string>;
  displayTypes$: Observable<boolean>;
  declarationTypes$: Observable<Declarationtype[]>;
  badges$: Observable<Badge[]>;
  selectedDeclarationType$: Observable<string>;
  selectedBadge$: Observable<Badge>;
  traderReference$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromDeclaraionType.State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromDeclarationTypeActions.LoadDeclarationType());
    this.store.dispatch(new fromDeclarationTypeActions.LoadBadges());

    this.errorMessage$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromDeclaraionType.getError));
    this.displayTypes$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromDeclaraionType.getToggleDeclarationTypes)
    );
    this.declarationTypes$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromDeclaraionType.getDeclarationTypes)
    );

    this.selectedDeclarationType$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromDeclaraionType.getCurrentDeclarationType)
    );

    this.badges$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromDeclaraionType.getBadges));

    this.selectedBadge$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromDeclaraionType.getCurrentBadge),
      tap(x => console.log('About to fetch current badge from store {0}', x))
    );

    this.traderReference$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromDeclaraionType.getTraderReference)
    );
  }

  checkChanged(value: boolean): void {
    console.log('About to dispatch toggle Display Declaration Types');
    this.store.dispatch(
      new fromDeclarationTypeActions.ToggleDeclarationTypes(value)
    );
  }

  onBlurTraderReferenceChange(value: string) {
    console.log('About to dispatch Set Trader Reference');
    this.store.dispatch(
      new fromDeclarationTypeActions.SetTraderReference(value)
    );
  }

  badgeCodeSelected(value: Badge) {
    console.log('About to dispatch Set Current Badge');
    console.log(value);
    this.store.dispatch(new fromDeclarationTypeActions.SetCurrentBadge(value));
  }
}
```

---

```
 <div class="declaration-type">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel
      [expanded]="displayTypes === true"
      (opened)="(displayTypes === true)"
    >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header
        [collapsedHeight]="customCollapsedHeight"
        [expandedHeight]="customExpandedHeight"
      >
        <mat-panel-title> <h4>Declaration Type</h4> </mat-panel-title>
        <label>
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            (change)="checkChanged($event.target.checked)"
            [checked]="displayTypes"
          />
          Display Types?
        </label>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <div class="controls-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flex-item-declarationType">
            <label class="field-label labelAlignment">
              Decln Type [01]:
              <mat-select class="declaration-type-combobox" [value]="selectedDeclarationType">
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="let declarationType of declarationTypes"
                  [value]="declarationType?.value"

                >
                  {{ declarationType.value }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item-badgeCode">
            <label class="field-label labelAlignment">
              Badge Codes:
              <mat-select class="badge-codes-combobox" [value]="selectedBadge" >
                <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="badgeCodeSelected(badge)"
                  *ngFor="let badge of badges"
                  [value]="badge?.code">
                 <div>{{ badge.code }} - {{ badge.name }}</div>
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flex-item-traderReference">
            <label class="field-label labelAlignment">
              Trader Reference [07]:
              <input
                matInput
                type="text"
                [(ngModel)]="traderReference"
                class="trader-reference-inputBox"
                (blur)="onTraderReferenceSet(traderReference)"
              />
              <button
                mat-button
                *ngIf="traderReference"
                matSuffix
                mat-icon-button
                aria-label="Clear"
                (click)="traderReferenceValue = ''"
              >
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-declaration-type',
  templateUrl: './declaration-type.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./declaration-type.component.scss']
})
export class DeclarationTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  customCollapsedHeight = '40px';
  customExpandedHeight = '40px';

  @Input() errorMessage: string;
  @Input() displayTypes: boolean;
  @Input() declarationTypes: Declarationtype[];
  @Input() badges: Badge[];
  @Input() selectedDeclarationType: string;
  @Input() selectedBadge: Badge;
  @Input() traderReference: string;

  @Output() checked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() declarationTypeSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() badgeSelected = new EventEmitter<Badge>();
  @Output() traderReferenceSet = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  checkChanged(value: boolean): void {
    this.checked.emit(value);
  }

  badgeCodeSelected(value: Badge) {
    this.badgeSelected.emit(value);
  }

  onTraderReferenceSet(value: string) {
    this.traderReferenceSet.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure this outmyself.. i feel like there is a race condition somewhere. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit of a shift for you, but I wanted to share that I have a library that, among other things, has built-in directives to bind form controls to a store. The big shift is that you'll need to build a `StoreObject` instead of using a selector, and you won't write or handle any actions.

The library is called [`ng-app-state`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state), and the key to the binding to form controls is in the `nasModel` directive. I'll give you an idea below.

Let's say the value for your checkbox is in the store at a place like this:

```
class DeclarationTypeState {
  badgeCode: string;
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <mat-select [nasModel]="badgeCodeStore">
      <mat-option ...></mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  `,
})
export class DeclarationTypeComponent {
  badgeCodeStore: StoreObject<string>;

  constructor(myStore: MyStore) {
    this.badgeCodeStore = myStore('keyForDeclarationTypeState')('badgeCode');
  }
}
```

This will do the 2-way binding into your store to make the `mat-select` stay in sync with the store, and edit the value in the store when the user changes it.

Comment: what is `nasModel`

Comment: @RicardoSaracino It is the directive provided by the library mentioned above that lets you bind to a store object from the same library. You can see the docs [here](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs/tree/master/projects/ng-app-state).